# Downloading a Laravel project from github

Tags: php, mysql, git, laravel

I dowloaded the following project from github:

https://github.com/deadwheel/FoodDelivery

I did the following steps:

1- Downloaded the files via git bash to my xamppp'shtdocs folder:
$ git clone https://github.com/deadwheel/FoodDelivery.git

2- Created the database forge on phpmyadmin.

3- I modified the config/database.php on the project's folder leaving it like this:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => 'innoDB',
        ],
```

4- Input the following commands:

$ composer update
$ php artisan migrate

With this, all the tables apperead on the database, but i got the following errors.

```
Connection.php line 664:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1825 Failed to add the foreign key constraint on table 'order_driver'. Incorrect options in FOREIGN KEY constraint 'forge/order_driver_deliverer_id_foreign' (SQL:
alter table `order_driver` add constraint `order_driver_deliverer_id_foreign` foreign key (`deliverer_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete NO ACTION)


 PDOStatement.php line 143:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1825 Failed to add the foreign key constraint on table 'order_driver'. Incorrect options in FOREIGN KEY constraint 'forge/order_driver_deliverer_id_foreign'


 PDOStatement.php line 141:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1825 Failed to add the foreign key constraint on table 'order_driver'. Incorrect options in FOREIGN KEY constraint 'forge/order_driver_deliverer_id_foreign'
```

I ignored the errors and tried opening the project on my browser going to:

https://laravel.test/FoodDelivery/public/

and i got the following error:

"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Is something missing? what else do i need to fix?

Comment: "Is something missing? what else do i need to fix?".... "I ignored the errors"

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps described on https://github.com/deadwheel/FoodDelivery

But i think they forget to add following steps

1. Create copy of .env.example with name .env

   This is your environment file which is required by laravel project
2. Open .env file and update this file with your MySQL Connection credentilas
3. After that run following command

   `php artisan key:generate`

   `php artisan config:cache`

   `composer dump-autoload`
4. After that run your migration commands

   `php artisan migrate`
5. Now Run your project with following command

   `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000`

Now you are done, you can browse project on

```
localhost:8000 | 127.0.0.1:8000 | 0.0.0.0:8000 | YOUR_IP:8000
```

I think this will help you out.

Comment: You might able to rename .env.example file to .env

Answer (score 1):

run the following commands.

```
1- composer install

2 -php artisan key:generate
```

and you are good to browse your app

Comment: I got the following error after php artisan key:generate:


In config.php line 714:

  Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state()

Comment: that is because you have uncomplete instalation of a package.